# В чем перспектива Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Для web и другие его возможности...

Answer (score 3):

Возможность быстрого построения веб приложений, не требующих работы при высокой нагрузке или сумасшедшего быстродействия (это скорее клише, возможны варианты). Очень любим за это стартаперами